# study vs studying at a university

Tags: present-tense

study vs studying at a university

Many say that both version are correct but to me the progressive aspect doesn't sit right here.
I wouldn't object using it in an example such as "I normally study at this university but this term I'm doing a course at a different one."
In short, I think that such a long period which frames university studies is not fleeting enough to warrant the present progressive, and it conjures up images of habit.

I guess the answer is that if you want to present your studies as more dynamic or more immediate, you will use the progressive form. What do you think?

Comment: Native Anglophones would normally say *I **am studying** at Oxford* rather than *I **study** at Oxford*, but both are perfectly valid. I wouldn't care to guess what the most common reason for choosing the less common phrasing might be (there's certainly no universally-understood implication to making that choice). But it's always *I **go to school** in a nearby town*, never *I **am going** to school* (that's non-standard "Indian English").

Comment: As with many phrases that people ask about here **it all depends on context**.